# Emacs. How cut all text contain "some_text/XXX" from another text?

Tags: search, replace, emacs

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

Suppose I has text:

```
    aa11aaa aaaaa "api/method1" bbbbbbb
dddeeee ee "api/method2" ddddddd
ee2222ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz "api/method1" eeeeeee
aaaaaaa222222222222"api/method3" fffffff
xwwwwxx "api/method4" bbbbbbb
```

I want to cut all text that contain **"api/XXX"**

, where **XXX** is a method name (e.g. **method4**)

. So the result must be:

`aa11aaa aaaaa bbbbbbb
dddeeee ee  ddddddd
ee2222ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz  eeeeeee
aaaaaaa222222222222 fffffff
xwwwwxx bbbbbbb`

I want to use built-in capabilities of Emacs (without write custom elisp script or Emacs macros).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is search for that string and *replace it with an empty string* (no characters):

With the cursor where you want to start searching and replacing, do this:

```
M-x replace-string RET api/XXX RET RET
```

Or if you need to match a regular-expression, use command `replace-regexp` instead.

Or if you want to check each search hit individually and tell Emacs whether to replace it, use `query-replace` (`M-%`) or `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-%`). You can hit `!` when queried to make replacements everywhere from the current position forward.

Use `C-h f` and enter a command name to get more information about that command. For example, `C-h f replace-string` tells you:

> **`replace-string`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `replace.el`.
>
> ```
> (replace-string FROM-STRING TO-STRING &optional DELIMITED START END BACKWARD)
> ```
>
> This function is for interactive use only;
>   in Lisp code use `search-forward` and `replace-match` instead.
>
> Replace occurrences of `FROM-STRING` with `TO-STRING`.
>
> Preserve case in each match if `case-replace` and `case-fold-search`
>   are non-`nil` and `FROM-STRING` has no uppercase letters.
>   (Preserving case means that if the string matched is all caps, or capitalized,
>   then its replacement is upcased or capitalized.)
>
> Ignore read-only matches if `query-replace-skip-read-only` is non-`nil`,
>   ignore hidden matches if `search-invisible` is `nil`, and ignore more
>   matches using `isearch-filter-predicate`.
>
> If `replace-lax-whitespace` is non-`nil`, a space or spaces in the string
>   to be replaced will match a sequence of whitespace chars defined by the
>   regexp in `search-whitespace-regexp`.
>
> If `replace-char-fold` is non-nil, matching uses character folding,
>   i.e. it ignores diacritics and other differences between equivalent
>   character strings.
>
> Third arg `DELIMITED` (prefix arg if interactive), if non-`nil`, means replace
>   only matches surrounded by word boundaries.  A negative prefix arg means
>   replace backward.
>
> Operates on the region between `START` and `END` (if both are `nil`, from point
>   to the end of the buffer).  Interactively, if Transient Mark mode is
>   enabled and the mark is active, operates on the contents of the region;
>   otherwise from point to the end of the buffer’s accessible portion.
>
> Use `M-n` to pull the last incremental search string to the minibuffer
>   that reads `FROM-STRING`.
>
> This function is usually the wrong thing to use in a Lisp program.
>
> What you probably want is a loop like this:
>
> ```
>   (while (search-forward FROM-STRING nil t)
>     (replace-match TO-STRING nil t))
> ```
>
> which will run faster and will not set the mark or print anything.
>   (You may need a more complex loop if `FROM-STRING` can match the null string
>   and `TO-STRING` is also null.)